# Is there an optimal loss function for dealing with imbalanced classes?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, unbalanced-classes

I'm aware that there are many ways of dealing with datasets where there is a strong class imbalance in the target variable: downsampling the more prevalent and less important class, over-weighting the valuable minority class, etc. Are there any loss functions that are ideally suited for these types of problems? I've heard of AUC, but AUC sounds like a means of evaluating a model once its training is complete (correct me if I'm wrong). Log loss and squared loss penalize a model's over confidence, but overconfidence and class imbalance seem unrelated. Is that true?

Answer (score 5):

Think for a moment about the phrase "optimal loss function". A loss function is what tells you what counts as a good prediction or a bad prediction. It is the basis on which you can assess whether a statistical method or model is optimal. Hence, there can be no such thing as an optimal loss function (unless perhaps you have committed to some kind of meta-loss-function or philosophical framework). Ultimately, you have to choose the loss function that represents what you care about for the problem in question.

> AUC sounds like a means of evaluating a model once its training is complete (correct me if I'm wrong)

I'm not sure what you mean by that, but area under the receiver operating characteristic curve is not a particularly good measure of anything, really.

> Log loss and squared loss penalize a model's over confidence, but overconfidence and class imbalance seem unrelated. Is that true?

Yes, they're distinct things. On the subject of overconfidence, if you're talking about the problem of [probabilistic classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_classification), log loss is much harsher than squared loss (i.e. the Brier score) on extreme predicted probabilities that are on the wrong side of 1/2. In particular, when the model predicts a probability of 0 for belonging to the class that a case ends up actually belonging to, that prediction is regarded as infinitely bad.